# Finding co-renters in Switzerland

Tags: rental, switzerland

We (me and my wife) are moving to St. Gallen, Switzerland in October-November 2019.
To reduce our rent costs we are totally fine to co-rent an apartment (or a detached house) with another family or a single person. Is this a common practice in Switzerland? Are there any established sites I can start looking for co-renters on?

Comment: This is not a question about expats

Comment: I disagree. The OP and his wife are moving to Switzerland, which suggests more than tourist-length tenure.

Answer (score 1):

Anibis is the main Swiss equivalent of Gum Tree and the like. That kind of thing can be hunted for there.

Also a lot of this goes on in Facebook groups. There will likely be a bunch of expats in St gallen and St gallen housing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Craigslist has a presence in Europe, and pages in the large Swiss cities including [Zurich](https://zurich.craigslist.org/?lang=en&cc=us). It has the same "Housing" categories we see in the US, and might yield something useful.